# What is the difference between %s and % in Python when embedding values in a string?

Tags: python, string

I'm a student that is recently learning some Python and would like some help in explaining the difference between `%s` and `%` in an embedded string, ill put a sample code below to show where exactly I'm struggling

```
>>> joke_text = '%s: a device for finding furniture in the dark'
>>> bodypart1 = 'Knee'
>>> bodypart2 = 'Shin'
>>> print(joke_text % bodypart1)
Knee: a device for finding furniture in the dark
>>> print(joke_text % bodypart2)
Shin: a device for finding furniture in the dark
```

I understand the `%s` is used as a marker to replace it with future variables which in this case are `bodypart1` and `bodypart2`. what confuses me is what the `%` symbol itself is doing in these areas:  `print(joke_text % bodypart1)` and `print(joke_text % bodypart2)`.

Any help is greatly appreciated and please let me know if you need me to further elaborate on anything
Thanks!

Comment: Here in your `joke_text` variable your `%s` is getting replaced by `%bodypart1` in the print command. Isn't that self-explanatory?

Comment: The `%` is an operator. If the left side operand is a string, string formatting is applied to it using the right side operand as the arguments.

Comment: Also, take a look at https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/ which explains in simple terms the various string formatting approaches in Python. The method you've used is the old-style method that most Python 2 code used. Since Python 3, `str.format` and f-strings are the preferred way.

Comment: Thank you, @costaparas that seemed to clear things up for me!